# How to add created NotificationChannel to GCP Error Reporting in Pulumi?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pulumi

I'm trying right now to replicate an existing GCP project set-up in Pulumi.
In GCP console you can add notification channels to Error Reporting via GUI like:

[image]

In Pulumi, I found out how to create a notification channel ([link to the docs](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/gcp/api-docs/monitoring/notificationchannel/)). Now, how can I add my created notification channels to GCP's Error Reporting via Pulumi?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Pulumi doc](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/gcp/api-docs/monitoring/notificationchannel/) and by using Pulumi you can only create notification channels and cannot add this notification channel to the Error report using Pulumi. The only way to  do this is using the [GCP Console](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/notifications?_ga=2.112522371.-687733801.1708081208#configure-notifications).

In GCP Console go to error reporting page,  Click on Configure notification as shown in below Fig(i)
[image: fig(i)]

[image: fig(ii)]

Post clicking on this  you see a fig(ii) as shown above. Click on the notification channels and select the notification channel which you created using Pulumi as shown in  below fig (iii). This will add your notification channel to Error reporting.

[image: Fig(iii)]

Comment: Where in the Pulumi docs does it say you "cannot add this notification channel to the Error report using Pulumi"? I cannot find such a passage.

Comment: @cis : As there is no documentation or information in Pulumi on adding notification channel to error report which assumes that there is no feasibility. You can also ask your question in [Pulumi](https://www.pulumi.com/ai) and check this [NewRelic AI Application Error Reporting through Custom Channels](https://www.pulumi.com/ai/answers/sRNjyrJ9ckZxc21qLdy9UW/monitoring-app-errors-with-newrelic-ai).

Comment: No, I did not find the answer useful. I find the conclusion "It's not mentioned in the docs, hence it's not possible" not convincing and I know myself how to set in in GCP Console. NB: My screenshot and your first screenshot are almost identical. Hence, no need to believe I would not know how to do that.

Comment: @cis : You can also ask your question in [PulumiAI](https://www.pulumi.com/ai) or File a feature request or bug on [pulumi GitHub](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-ai/issues). So it will be useful for every one in this community.